# POST checkbox a value

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help me fix this code so that the checkbox selected will take the value of a variable row number. I'm not concern with it working as an array until I can get this basic line of code first. Thanks.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<h2>FILMS : </h2>";   
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";   
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";   
echo    "

<td width='20' align='center'>#</td>
<td width='20' align='center'>ID</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>TITLE</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>ROLE</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>DIRECTOR</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id_actor= $row["id_actor"];

$idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
$filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
$filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
$filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


//Here's the Problem
    echo"<tr>";
echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" 
value="id_actor"  //POST a value that equals a variable row selected? 
type="checkbox" 
id="checkbox[]" /></td>';

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)  
    {
        echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
   }
 echo"</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace your  creation with following code

```
$row_number = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id_actor= $row["id_actor"];
    $idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
    $filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
    $filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
    $filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


    //Here's the Problem
    echo"<tr>";
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" value="id_actor'.$row_number.'" type="checkbox" 
    id="checkbox'.$row_number.'" /></td>';

    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)  {
       echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";

    $row_number++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a seperate html form with a delete button that doesn't seem to post.  How can I add a delete button in this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want to accomplish or not but here it goes.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<h2>FILMS : </h2>";   
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";   
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";   
echo    "

<td width='20' align='center'>#</td>
<td width='20' align='center'>ID</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>TITLE</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>ROLE</td>
<td width='200' align='center'>DIRECTOR</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id_actor= $row["id_actor"];

$idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
$filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
$filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
$filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


//Here's the Problem
echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$id_actor.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$idfilm.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$filmTitle.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$filmRole.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$filmDirector.'" /></td>';

    echo '</tr>';

   }
 echo"</table>";
```